# Breezejs/Angular/EF - cannot execute until metadastore is populated

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, breeze

I started to learn angularjs and trying to put together Angularjs+Breezejs+EntityFramework.

Here is my context cs file:

```
public class GrantsDbContext : DbContext {
    public GrantsDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<GrantsDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<GrantsDbContext, Configuration>());
    }
    public DbSet<OrgItem> OrgList;
}
```

OrgItem is just model-class (contained: ID, FullName, ShortName), and I set automigrate, and write default connection string in Web.config

That's breeze controller cs file:

```
[BreezeController]
public class DbController : ApiController {
    private EFContextProvider<GrantsDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<GrantsDbContext>();
    [HttpGet]
    public String Metadata() {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<OrgItem> OrgList() {
        return _contextProvider.Context.OrgList;
    }
}
```

Here is angular service, that created manager for breeze:

```
angular.module('app').factory("entityManagerFactory", ["breeze", emFactory]);

function emFactory(breeze) {

    new breeze.ValidationOptions({ validateOnAttach: false }).setAsDefault();

    var serviceName = "breeze/db";
    var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();

    var provider = {
        newManager: newManager
    };

    return provider;

    function newManager() {
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: serviceName,
            metadataStore: metadataStore
        });
        return mgr;
    }
}
```

That's my controller that called query:

```
angular.module("app")
    .controller("OrgCtrl", ['entityManagerFactory', OrgCtrl]);

function OrgCtrl(entityManagerFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.orgs = [];

    var manager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();
    var orgsQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery("OrgList").select("ID, FullName, ShortName");
    manager.executeQuery(orgsQuery).then(succesCallback).catch(failCallback);

    function succesCallback(data) {
        vm.orgs = data.result;
    }
    function failCallback(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

When I firstly started the app, database was created with one table '_MigrationHistory' and then I got the error: 'Error: cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated.'

'localhost:49934/breeze/db/Metadata' is available (200 OK).
All libraries updated with nuget.

Help please to solve this problem!
Thanks!

Comment: For clarity, are you saying that entering `localhost:49934/breeze/db/Metadata` in a browser address bar does return metadata?

Comment: We can talk about other issues later ... such as the pros and cons (mostly cons) of performing persistence operations in an ng controller and, specifically, of creating a new manager for each ng controller.